How many independent test transceiver modules are truly required for MIMO testing?
In most if not all of the app notes I have ever seen from the major test equipment vendors, such as R&S and Keysight, it is strongly implied if not explicitly stated that in order to do an NxN MIMO test with a radio DUT (let's assume SU-MIMO for simplicity), you need N vector signal generators (if your DUT is to receive and demodulate signals in Rx mode) and N vector signal analyzers (if demodulating signals coming out from your DUT in Tx mode).  Sometimes you can get the generator/analyzer capability combined within single test modules to reduce the total number of physical test modules needed, but the same principle applies regardless.
Is it ever possible to do a "real" MIMO test without satisfying the N requirement stated above?  Would it be possible, for example, to do a 4x4 MIMO test with only 1 generator/analyzer by cleverly using passive components such as combiners/dividers, phase shifters, and attenuators between said generator/analyzer and your DUT (assuming the DUT has 4 antennas/channels)?


Is it ever possible to do a "real" MIMO test without satisfying the N requirement stated above?

Well, it depends on what you mean with "real MIMO test", but in generally, you're testing a device for the purpose of understanding how it works in a MIMO environment. So you need a true N×N channel matrix.

Would it be possible, for example, to do a 4x4 MIMO test with only 1 generator/analyzer by cleverly using passive components such as combiners/dividers, phase shifters, and attenuators between said generator/analyzer and your DUT (assuming the DUT has 4 antennas/channels)?

No. You need to be able to simultaneously test, over the whole bandwidth, so tricks like diplexing don't apply, how the device works with uncorrelated inputs. So, shifting, delaying or otherwise passively modifying the signal that you feed into one input is inherently not sufficient. You're building a correlated channel, something that is frequency-selective, but not a MIMO channel; unless you do MIMO only for the beamforming aspects, the point is that there's statistically uncorrelated channels that you can find in your MIMO channel matrix. If you apply deterministic transform (and that's all your devices can do), you cannot induce uncorrelatedness. That's actually quite close to something that I remember being asked as a student to see whether I understood what the difference between a plain multi-antenna system and a MIMO system is.
You can of course try to do things like terminate all inputs of your DUT but one, feed in a known signal, terminate all outputs but one, and measure one output after the other, for each input, to get an equivalent H-matrix. However, that is a characterization of the device assuming it just is a linear MIMO channel - but you're testing a device's functionality, not something where you know beforehand that it's just a linear channel. (That would not be a very useful radio device, usually, unless your radio device is a channel emulator. If you build channel emulators, and I've seen prices that Keysight is willing to demand for them, then you wouldn't be asking for a second signal analyzer…)
Honestly, though, for the price of one Keysight signal analyzer, you can buy typically multiple 4×4 capable SDR setups. Sure, these aren't going to amplitude- and phase calibrated, but absolute phase very rarely matters, and you'd really need to shell out big bucks for reliable, de-embedded test setups with defined cable lengths and everything. But for amplitude, you can use a splitters on each in- and output and terminators to these that you're currently not observing to calibrate your SDR's outputs and its input- to digital amplitude mapping. (Technically, that's possible for phase as well, but then we're back at the problem that you'll need a signal analyzer with at least two input channels to be able to relate phases.)
Disclaimer: I freelance in a technical capacity for Ettus/NI, and they do make offer, some, SDR devices that have 4×4 channels and can be phase-aligned to allow for higher channel counts. There's also and some with 2×2 channels that allow at least for reference clock sharing to combine them, and some cheaper 2×2 USB ones. I'm not getting any kickbacks from sales.

"However, that is a characterization of the device assuming it just is a linear MIMO channel - but you're testing a device's functionality, not something where you know beforehand that it's just a linear channel. (That would not be a very useful radio device, usually, unless your radio device is a channel emulator."
I am a little confused by this- can you clarify a little bit further on this point?  Why would this make the radio device not useful, for example?

no, that's not what I said. I said "testing the device as if it was a linear channel makes no sense. It's a useful device, that's why you're testing it."

@MarcusMüller - Hi, Re your comment: "no, that's not what I said" Yes, it really is! The OP's comment quoted directly from the answer (specifically from the 5th paragraph, including paragraphs which are quotes). Obviously it's fine if you meant the answer to say what you put in the comment instead, but that's different from commenting that the OP is misquoting you (they aren't). People are making us aware of this apparent contradiction, so can you clarify, please? TY

Sorry! You're right, I should have said "that's not what I meant". But I really did not say that that I'm making the device useless, @SamGibson. I'm fine with being asked to be more careful in my reactions, not fine with being miscorrected.

@MarcusMüller - I'm not sure what your last sentence means, but going back to the point that other users were contacting mods about: If I understand correctly, you've kindly clarified that you weren't challenging the quote from the answer (as some people were interpreting your comment). Instead you were clarifying that you didn't mean the device would be useless. I'm just trying to get this clear, to avoid yet more flags. || I recommend that you post a "new comment 2" in this thread to clarify, and then I'll delete from the "old comment 2" down to your replacement. Does that make sense?

I must admit I'm not 100% following you, but will check on this later, @SamGibson
